# Migración en ruby on rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Al realizar este comando:

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_articles user::references
```

Salta este error al realizar `rake db:migrate` sale este error:

> rake aborted! SyntaxError:
>   C:/laragon/www/ProyectRuby/blog/db/migrate/20180810162705_add_user_id_to_articles.rb:3:
>   syntax error, unexpected ':'
>
> Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 1):

tienes un pequeño error, te sobra un ":".  El comando correcto es:

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_articles user:references
```

Ah! y según la documentación, lo "correcto" sería así (CamelCase):

```
rails g migration AddUserIdToArticles user:references
```

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Entonces podrías marcarla como correcta... digo yo xD

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda